# Git Bash error-reset

Tags: git, git-bash

I've just started using Git Bash for executing my code, I tried to set it up for using python and anaconda, and when setting it up I misspelled a command line, and an error occurs every time I start the program. It doesn't accept any commands, I tried to reinstall it several times, but nothing changed.I'd be grateful if someone could help me fixing the problem.

[image]

Comment: You have messed up your `export PATH="...` in one of the bash startup files (by deleting `PATH=`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminals - copy the text into a code block instead.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to `export PATH` (export the variable named "PATH") rather than `export $PATH` (export the variable corresponding to the *contents* of the `PATH` variable).